# How to get underlying class name from Facade name in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-facade

I am finding it a bit difficult to understand Facades. Particularly how to find the underlying class name/location from a facade name. I have gone through the documentation but still not clear. For example, when using `Auth::login()` 
, i found that there is no `login()` method in the **Auth** facade.

```
 class Auth extends Facade
{
/**
 * Get the registered name of the component.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
{
    return 'auth';
}

/**
 * Register the typical authentication routes for an application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public static function routes()
 {
    static::$app->make('router')->auth();
 }
}
```

The **Auth** facades `getFacadeAccessor()` method returns a string **auth**. But to which `auth` class should i be looking at? How to resolve the actual class?

Thanks,

Comment: This might be helpfull https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/facades#how-facades-work If you scroll a bit down you will see which facade corresponds to which class

Comment: Brilliant question. It's been driving me nuts for a long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere in a Serviceprovider the `auth` key is registered to something. For the `auth` key that's in `vendor/laravel/frameworksrc/Illuminate/Auth/AuthServiceProvider.php`. You can see that in the `registerAuthenticator()` method, the `auth` key is registered to the `Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager` with a singleton pattern.

The container has several ways to bind a key to a specific class. methods like `bind` and `singleton` for example. Facades are just an extra class to call the main class statically from the root namespace.

If you want to check out which class is used, you can use the following code: `get_class(resolve('auth'))`. Ofcourse, you can replace auth with any string you want to check.

Bonus: I think you can override this behaviour by registering your own manager in some kind of way. I would advise you to extend the normal `AuthManager` and overwrite the methods that you want to see changed.

Comment: Hi Mark. How does the application know that to resolve 'app' it has to go to the class `Illuminate/Auth/AuthServiceProvider.php`?

Comment: You register the AuthServiceProvider in the `config/app.php` file. If you register it there, it will execute the `boot` and `register` method on startup.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `getFacadeRoot()`

For example

```
$object = Auth::getFacadeRoot() // Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager instance
```

or to get the fully qualified class name

```
$class = get_class(Auth::getFacadeRoot()) // 'Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager'
```

Also you can use the container to resolve a class by it's accessor. This is what Laravel does under the hood when resolving a Facade.

```
$object = resolve('auth'); // Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager instance
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to utilise the `@see` annotations on the facade

```
/**
 * @see \Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager
 * @see \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory
 * @see \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard
 * @see \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
 */
class Auth extends Facade
```

Usually the method should exist on these classes/interfaces

For example, `Auth::check()` exists on `\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard::check()`.

If you use an editor that allows you to follow through these definitions it can be a bit easier to traverse. Usually there's only one `@see` annotation so it's pretty easy to find the class.

Comment: Hi morph. Yes sublime text has this feature. But i wanted to learn how to resolve this on my own. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getFacadeRoot()` on the package/service to get its object:

For example, I write a helper function to get `Facade` object so I can use that `Cart` object with ease from anywhere:

```
function cart() {
    return \Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart::getFacadeRoot();
}
```